# How do I reload my page in remix run on a button click in an error boundary component

Tags: typescript, remix.run

I have made an error boundary component in my remix app and have a retry button in it. But how do I add the functionality of reload? error boundary component is in root.tsx.

Answer (score 3):

Remember, Remix uses `react-router` under the hood.

```js
const navigate = useNavigate()
const handleClick = () => {
  navigate('.', { replace: true })
}
```

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate

Comment: do we have a way to not use `useNavigate` and perform this task?

Comment: <form method="get"><button>Retry</button></form>

Comment: ```const handleClick = () => {
 window.location.reload()
}``` how about using this? Is it any different than the navigate from react-router?

Answer (score 0):

https://remix.run/docs/en/1.19.3/hooks/use-revalidator

```
import { useRevalidator } from "@remix-run/react";

function WindowFocusRevalidator() {
  const revalidator = useRevalidator();

  useFakeWindowFocus(() => {
    revalidator.revalidate();
  });

  return (
    <div hidden={revalidator.state === "idle"}>
      Revalidating...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Refresh button in your Error Boundary Component:

```
import { useNavigate } from '@remix-run/react';
....
....
export function ErrorBoundary() {
...
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    .....
    return(
    ....
    <button onClick={() => navigate(`${homePageURL}`)}>Go Back</button>
    ....
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`useRevalidate`](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/hooks/use-revalidator) is the correct method, however, it is very important that you wrap it in a `revalidator.state` check like so:

```
if (revalidator.state === 'idle') {
  revalidator.revalidate();
}
```

Otherwise you will run into an infinite loop: https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/7835